# Having multiple paths to the same page with the auto_route package in Flutter

Tags: flutter, routes, flutter-web, bloc

## Is there a way to have several paths pointing to the same page?

To give some context: I have a flutter app that handles screens via Bloc events. The Home HomeScreen can have multiple events, each showing a specific page. Hence the need to have multiple paths pointing to the same screen.

The following is an example of how I have tried to set up routes. Build it doesn't work.

```
@MaterialAutoRouter(
  routes: <AutoRoute>[
    AutoRoute(path: '/routeA', page: HomeScreen),
    AutoRoute(path: '/routeB', page: HomeScreen),
    AutoRoute(path: '/routeC', page: HomeScreen),
    AutoRoute(path: '/routeD', page: HomeScreen),
  ]
)
```

Answer (score 3):

My solution to this is creating different classes that point to the same widget.

So in your case, if you have the class `'HomeScreen'` you, want to create classes that point to it.

```
 class HomeScreenRouteTwo extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreenRouteTwo({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return HomeScreen('specificData');
  }
}

 class HomeScreenRouteThree extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreenRouteThree({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return HomeScreen('specificData');
  }
}
```

And in your router

```
@MaterialAutoRouter(
 routes: <AutoRoute>[
  AutoRoute(path: 'routeA', page: HomeScreenRouteTwo),
  AutoRoute(path: 'routeB', page: HomeScreenRouteThree),
   ... etc
  ]
)
```

This will do the same effect with different paths that point to the same widget you've built, but makes you able to send in different information based on the path you send the user to.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: clever approach.

Answer (score 1):

> HomeScreen can have multiple events, each showing a specific page. Hence the need to have multiple paths pointing to the same screen.

If homepage has multiple events, handle what the users sees in the home page

eg

```
event 1
  show user picture of a cat
event 2
  show user picture of a dog.
```

Comment: This is exactly what I do. 

But I want to know if it is possible to have different paths for the same page.